# How to make the linked text colorful in beamer.

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I want to highlight linked text with different color in beamer. 
for example, my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{tex.stackexchange.com}
My first Question: 
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224863/package-pgf-error-no-shape-named-is-  known}{Package pgf Error: No shape named is known}
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

I want  to highlight the

> package-pgf-error-no-shape-named-is-  known

with different color, can anybody help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty is to use `\alert`:

```
\alert{Package pgf Error: No shape named is known}
```

[image]

or to pass `colorlinks` option to

```
\documentclass[a4paper,colorlinks]{beamer}
```

[image]

```
%\documentclass[a4paper,colorlinks]{beamer}
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{tex.stackexchange.com}
My first Question:
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224863/package-pgf-error-no-shape-named-is-  known}{\alert{Package pgf Error: No shape named is known}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Then play with the colours of course .

Comment: Thank you very much, I have another question: how to customize the color for text, for example, green?

Comment: @WangyanLi With `hyperref`, Use something like `\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=green}` and for `\alert` it is defined by the theme, so choose a theme.

Comment: Many thanks, you have solved all problems I had.

Comment: @WangyanLi You are welcome. :-)